# Turn off tooltips in Eclipse / Aptana

Tags: eclipse

I don't know if anyone has noticed that Eclipse has this annoying feature where it needs to show a useless tool-tip when hovering just about anything.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to completely kill all tool-tip behavior in Eclipse / Aptana?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found mine in Window > Preferences > Pydev > Editor > Hovers

It looks like it's a module-level feature (Java, Pydev, C++), not platform-level (Eclipse itself).

Comment: That's the stuff! Just disable Combined Hover. You can bring it up by stepping on the word and pressing F2.

Answer (score 9):

Window > Preferences > Java > Editors > Hovers

Disable Combined Hover.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not able to find this option in Aptana. Is this a Eclipse 3.4 feature maybe?

Comment: I guess it's because I don't have any Java editors installed.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, hints can be really annoying, but there are times when they can be a really useful quick reference - like finding var values during debugging, or required parameter types for a method etc.

So instead of disabling them altogether, or continually enbaling/disabling through the Preferences, I go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Hovers > Combined Hover, and add Alt to the **Pressed key modifier while hovering** field below.

This way if you want to quickly see hints just hold the Alt key down.

Answer (score 5):

I was completely annoyed with Aptana's tip tool text over my code. I figured out how to disable it:

**Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Content Assist > Show information on hover > Off**

I'm using Aptana 3.

Comment: This is pretty annoying. Especially when you are trying to arrow down and it keeps popping up forcing you to have to move the mouse to make it go away.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing which really annoys me on Eclipse are the light bulbs in the left part which hide breakpoints, and which are really useless.

To suppress these, go to windows>preference>java>editor and then uncheck "Light bulb for quick assists".

If you dont have this on your eclipse version, try a help search with "light bulb".

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. Change the Windows regedit.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER ->Control Panel -> Mouse -> mouse -> MouseHoverTime
Change its value to be 400 (4 seconds delay)

http://untamedmind.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/changing-the-mousehovertime-add-delay-on-the-tooltips-pop-up/

Answer (score -1):

Look for TweakUI settings, under Mouse > Hover.  Minimize the sensitivity and increase the time and you will, in most cases, be fine.

Note that this is under windows.  In any case, search for "hover" and you should be able to find the correct location.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry. I'm on Linux. This TweakUI thing is a Windows thing not an Eclipse thing, is that right? I just want to turn off all tooltips in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with Ecplise or other editors.