# How to Disable Html/CSS Code Assist in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: html, css, web, aptana

How to disable Code Hints of HTML and CSS in Aptana Studio 3. I searched various options but can't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300679/125528

Answer (score 6):

To sandbox,

The thing that you have mention is called **Content Asisst**. It will show a code-assist when you typing a code related to HTML/CSS.

To disable Content Assist in Aptana Studio 3 is :
Choose **Window** in the main menu ( menu avaiable on top) → **Preferences** → Choose **Aptana Studio** → **Content Assist** → Look at the **Auto-display content asisst** then you will see the **drop down menu** at besides, then click drop-down menu choose **Off** instead of **Default delay**.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are referring to is most likely resolved in the beta of 3.0.4, but if you need to turn code assist off, I would suggest:

a) **Preferences > Aptana > Editors (main node)**

b) **Preferences > Aptana > Editors > JavaScript (for example) and check the activation triggers**. You may wish to remove "(" and "." for example.